# How to print undefined attribute in Angular table?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an angular object from a class with multiple attributes.

Example:

```
export class test{
    public name: any;
    public age: any;
    public city: any;
}
```

On execution I fill most part of the object attributes from a JSON (not all) and then I represent those attributes on a table. At this point my obj class has the `city` attribute with no value.

```
obj = JSON.parse(serverResult);
```

On `.html`:

```
<table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td scope="col">Name</td>
            <td scope="col">Age</td>
            <td scope="col">City</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>{{obj.Name}}</td>
            <td>{{obj.Age}}</td>
            <td>{{obj.City}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

When trying to print the undefined values I get the following error:

> Cannot read property 'City' of undefined

How can I avoid this error without checking if undefined? Thanks!

Comment: `JSON.parse(serverResult)` parses a string to a JSON. Are you sure this is what you want ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error says `obj` is undefined, not City. So all you have to do is adding a `*ngIf`, so you wait for the object to be defined before printing it:

```
<table class="table table-striped" *ngIf="obj">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td scope="col">Name</td>
            <td scope="col">Age</td>
            <td scope="col">City</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>{{obj.Name}}</td>
            <td>{{obj.Age}}</td>
            <td>{{obj.City}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

an other solution would be to add a null-safe operator `?` to each property:

```
<table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td scope="col">Name</td>
            <td scope="col">Age</td>
            <td scope="col">City</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>{{obj?.Name}}</td>
            <td>{{obj?.Age}}</td>
            <td>{{obj?.City}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3):

you can use *ngIf as specified in other ans Or you can use null safe operator like

```
{{obj?.City}}
```

Answer (score 1):

You might simply do a null check, like

```
<td>{{obj?.Name}}</td>
<td>{{obj?.Age}}</td>
<td>{{obj?.City}}</td>
```

In case you want to write some filler text you might as well do something like

```
<td>{{obj ? obj.Name: 'some name'}}</td>
<td>{{obj ? obj.Age: 'some age'}}</td>
<td>{{obj ? obj.City: 'some City'}}</td>
```